# @Html.BeginForm not working under the @If statement in Razor Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is my razor code:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
@if (Model.InvoiceStatus == "NEW")
{                                                                              
    Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Invoices", new { InvoiceID = Model.InvoiceID, @returnUrl = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()) }, FormMethod.Post);

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Invoice" class="btn btn-danger newbtn" style="float:right;margin-left:10px;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this Invoice details?');" />

    Html.EndForm();

    @Html.ActionLink("Lock Invoice", "Lock", new { InvoiceID = Model.InvoiceID }, new { @class = "btn newbtn", @style = "float:right;margin-left:10px;" })

    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Invoice", "Edit", new { InvoiceID = Model.InvoiceID }, new { @class = "btn newbtn", @style = "float:right;margin-left:10px;" })

}

    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default newbtn", @style = "width:100px;float:right;" })
</div>
```

The code didnt recognize the html.beginform, it just renders as input tag,

```
<input value="Delete Invoice" class="btn btn-danger newbtn" style="float:right;margin-left:10px;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this Invoice details?');" type="submit">
```

Why it is not rendering as form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like

```
@if (Model.InvoiceStatus == "NEW")
{
  using(Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Invoices", new { InvoiceID = Model.InvoiceID,
       @returnUrl = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()) },
                                                                     FormMethod.Post))
 {
  <!-- Your form elements goes here -->
 }
}
```

This will generate the form tag when razor executes your code.

**EDIT :** *From the comments*

**You should not have nested forms!** That is invalid html. But you can still keep more than one form in the page (not nested, but siblings) as needed.

Comment: It should generate the form tag. what is the markup it is generating ?

Comment: <input value="Delete Invoice" class="btn btn-danger newbtn" style="float:right;margin-left:10px;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this Invoice details?');" type="submit">

Comment: It should work fine. Here is the dot net fiddle sample which works https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOUbU5 . Make sure that you have 2 closing brackets at the end, one for `BeginForm` method and one for `using`

Comment: I have a tag called <form class="form-horizontal"> somewhere above this code and closing at the bottom of the page as </form>.. does it cause any problem for Beginform?

Comment: **You should not have nested forms!** That is invalid markup. Take a look at the dot net fiddle link i posted. It generates the correct form tag markup.

Comment: Thanks @shyju...  Got the solution... it was the nested forms causing me the problem.. Now it working fine